# Send qml registered enum to c++ method as parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have class with `enum` like this

```cpp
class ScreenOrientation : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum Orientation {
        Unspecified = -1,
        Landscape = 0,
        Portrait = 1
    };
    Q_ENUM(Orientation)
};
```

registered with

```cpp
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ScreenOrientation>("Foo", 1, 0, "ScreenOrientation", QStringLiteral("Not creatable as it is an enum type"));
```

And my QML code:

```
backend.setOrientation(ScreenOrientation.Landscape)
```

It is working when my C++ method have `int` as argument

```cpp
...
void setOrientation(int orientation);
...
```

But if I use `ScreenOrientation::Orientation` as method argument I get "**Error: Unknown method parameter type: ScreenOrientation::Orientation**". Can I somehow use `ScreenOrientation::Orientation` as method argument? It looks much prettier than just `int`.

Comment: Should work as expected. There is nice enum tutorial [here](https://qml.guide/enums-in-qt-qml/) and I see it uses the same approach as yours. What Qt version do you use? Before 5.5 you have to use `Q_ENUMS`, not `Q_ENUM`. Maybe `qRegisterMetaType` is what you missed.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I'm using Qt 5.15.0, so Q_ENUM is my variant. I have no problem with registering and using C++ enums in QML code. But the problem comes up when I try to send it to C++ slot, that have my `enum` as parameter. Is it the only way to use `int` as slot argument? I can't use my `enum` for this in any way?

Comment: Thank you @folibis! All I had to do was add `qRegisterMetaType<ScreenOrientation::Orientation>()` in addition to register uncreatable type as you said. So I think you should create an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `qRegisterMetaType<ScreenOrientation::Orientation>()` in addition to `qmlRegisterUncreatableType()`.

Comment: What if enum wasn't in a class and in a namespace instead (and therefore the `Q_NAMESPACE` + `Q_ENUM_NS` combination used) ? Adding the `qmlRegisterMetaType<...>` doesn't work.